# In Continuous Deployment: Does the production codebase's file structure completely reset?

Tags: devops, continuous-deployment

I want to have a .env file in the production codebase, but do not want it on github.
So I asked my colleague to add the file through terminal access on the production server.

My colleague told me that every time we merge with main, the entire directory structure on the production server resets, so we cannot do that? Is there a work around this?

I thought even in CD the production server just does an automatic "git pull origin main".

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Dotenv is to simulate locally the real production environment. In production, _set actual env vars_.

Comment: The environment variables are needed to be used in my codebase. For example secret keys and other PII stuff is stored in the .env file and then I use that in a file called a.py. So to access that file, I do something like "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), ".env")" in the codebase, but if in the production codebase, the dotenv file is not in the expected place in the directory structure, then this code will error out. 

So by setting "actual env vars", do you mean having a .env file in the right place in the directory structure? @jonrsharpe

Sorry, If this is too vague, new to devops

Comment: Yes, I know what they're for. No, not a .env file, again that's a dev tool. Real env vars, how to set them will depend on the, uh, env.

Comment: Okay, I will look into that. 

You've been helpful, but there is one thing I am confused about. If we don't have a .env file on production, then wouldn't that line where I try to do this "os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), ".env")" , result in an error? Since it won't be able to find any such file in the directory. Because in local dev, I am just using the contents from the .env file, so my code expects it to be there.

Comment: Your code should tolerate no .env file being present, because it won't be needed to load into the environ, because there'll be real env vars. This is what the existing implementations of the dotenv pattern do, just use one of those.